# $A = \{a, b, c, d\}$ and $B = \{1, 2, 3\}$. How many functions from $A$ to $B$ map $a$ to $1$ and are not onto?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

[image]

I'm not sure how to do this. I know what an onto function is but I'm not sure how to start.

Comment: There are so few cases you could simply enumerate them. You already know $f(a) = 1$, so it only remains to see where $b, c, d$ are mapped.

Comment: @Stuy Recall that "The person who asked can mark one answer as *accepted*".

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**:

If a function $f$ is not onto, knowing that $a$ maps to $1$, it misses $2$ or $3$ or both. So there are two main cases:

1. $f$ misses  $2$. The number of  such functions is equal to the number of functions from the set $\{b,c,d\}$ to the set$\{1,3\}$.
2. Symmetrically, if $f$ misses  $3$, the number of  such functions is equal to the number of functions from the set $\{b,c,d\}$ to the set$\{1,2\}$.

The number of functions which map  $a$ to $1$ and are not onto is the union of these two sets. You can apply the inclusion-exclusion formula.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f$ be such a function.  We are given $f(a) =1$ and $\{f(b), f(c), f(d)\} \subsetneq \{1,2,3\}$.  So how many ways are there to be non-onto?

- $b$, $c$, and $d$ all get sent to $1$, or
- all get sent to $2$, or
- all get sent to $3$.
- $b$, $c$, and $d$ all get sent to $1$ and $2$, or
- to $1$ and $3$,
- (but not to $2$ and $3$ because then $f$ is onto).

You should be able to count each of those easily enough and to see that there are no other options.

Answer (score 0):

Use the inclusion-exclusion principle.

The number of functions $A \to B$ that map $a$ to $1$ is 27. To not be surjective (or onto) means that either 2 or 3 is not in the image. Of the 27 functions satisfying (a), 8 of them do not have 2 in the image, and another 8 do not have 3 in the image. One function, the constant function that is everywhere equal to 1, has neither 2 nor 3 in its image.

The answer is that there are $8+8-1=15$ functions satisfying both (a) and (b).

Comment: How is the number of functions A -> B that map a to 1 = 27?

Comment: There are 3 choices each for the images of b, c, and d, so the answer is $3^3=27$.

Comment: And how do you find out that 8 out of the 27 functions don't have 2 in the image? Likewise for 3?

Comment: If 2 is not in the image, then b, c, and d must each map to either 1 or 3, so there are $2^3=8$ such functions. Similarly, if 3 is not in the image, then b, c, and d must each map to either 1 or 2, so there are again 8 such functions.